# Use .htaccess to point URL with two parameters to URL with GET variable

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use .htaccess to point URLs such as these:

`www.test.com/regio/bar/foo`
`www.test.com/regio/something/blabla`

To `www.test/com/regio/bar/?var = foo` and `www.test/com/regio/something/?var = blabla`

I have tried this so far:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^regio/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ regio/$1/var=$2 [L]
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It writes what you give it. Your replacement has no `?` so the `var=$2` is not a `GET` but a path.

https://regex101.com/r/nQ8iW7/1

so try:

```
RewriteRule ^regio/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ regio/$1/?var=$2 [L]
```

and I think it will work for you.

https://regex101.com/r/nQ8iW7/2

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but I'm getting a 404 when I go to the page. (`www.test.com/regio/bar/foo` gives me a 404 and `www.test.com/regio/bar/`) doesn't. Do you know what is causing this?

Comment: And `www.test.com/regio/bar/?var=foo` loads for you?

Comment: Yes that does load for me

Comment: The `htaccess` is at the root and you have `RewriteBase /` in place?

Comment: I do. It's on a wordpress website by the way: would that matter?

Comment: Hmm I haven't worked with wordpress in a while and when I did it was minimal. Do any htaccess rules work for you?

Comment: @user1760791 Whats the status here?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

`RewriteRule ^regio/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/?$ regio/$1?page=$2 [NC,L]`

Comment: Why try this? There are no numbers in the OPs URLs. `regio/bar/foo`.

Comment: I just added it for sample piece which I used sometime before. Now updated for alpha numeric, you can include different characters also if required.